# Joomla says it's missing native ZIP support on CentOS 6.6

Tags: centos-6, joomla

I am trying to set up a Joomla site and on a new dedicated server running CentOS 6.6.  When installing Joomla, it is asking for "Native Zip Support" which is showing as "off" during the install. I need to enable it and am not sure what to do.  Can anyone point me in the right direction?  I tried `yum install php-pecl-zip` but it's not in the package manager.

Comment: just some information cent 6.6  php 5.4.42

Comment: BTW, your question title and tags are pretty awful - this problem has absolutely nothing to do with `ssh`; your problem is with getting a dependency of Joomla installed. You can just google "Joomla native zip" to get a bunch of very helpful results. I've made extensive edits to your question, title, and tags to suggest how you can write better questions in the future.

Comment: it actually does have alot to do with ssh because i cant enable it without knowing  ssh to configure the server. and having no knowledge with linux and ssh.   there is no point and click button to install  stuff. or i wouldnt be attempting to get answers. like my name says i have no clue.  i have went to a bunch of google posts.  including this one  Also, according to some sources, zip support can be enabled in the server by executing the following command with root rights:

1

 

yum install php-pecl-zip

Please note, the mentioned command is compatible only with CentOS server environment.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the `php-common` package *should* provide the equivalent of `php-pecl-zip` on CentOS 6.6; see [here](http://rpmfind.net//linux/RPM/centos/6.6/x86_64/Packages/php-common-5.3.3-38.el6.x86_64.html)

If that doesn't work, try this much more comprehensive tutorial [here](https://github.com/rharmonson/richtech/wiki/Installing-Joomla-3-on-CentOS-6.5-Minimal-x86_64), which provides an installation of Joomla from a third-party package repository. This is a more reliable way to go, because it will automatically install all required dependencies.

Comment: thanks for that info i am looking at that full tutorial and went to see the first link but still a little confused on how i would load that package   tried to google it  lol. the second link is  usefull just need to piece that together since i already have joomla installed  just need the zip so i can add components. but thank you :)

Comment: Step 0: Set up the yum-priorities plugin: http://wiki.centos.org/PackageManagement/Yum/Priorities
Step 1: Enable the EPEL repository: http://wiki.centos.org/AdditionalResources/Repositories
Step 2: Install the php-pecl-zip extension package:

Code: Select all
    yum install php-pecl-zip    i can get to step 2  No package php-pecl-zip available.
is there something i am missing